# Background image not showing CSS/PHP

Tags: html, css

The background image is not showing. I must be missing something but going a bit cross-eyed trying to work out what it is.

This is what I have:

```html
<div class="hero_text item">
  <h3><?php echo $slide['slide_title']; ?></h3>
  <p>
    <?php echo $slide[ 'slide_desc']; ?>
  </p>
  <img style="background-image:url(<?php echo $slide['slide_image']; ?>)"></img>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```css
.hero_text img {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Uhm... you declare the background ON THE ELEMENT, in CSS. Not as an `<img>`-tag. What element are you trying to have the background image on? An `<img>` element should NOT have a background image, it is there to display an actual image...

Comment: Yes you're right luka. I should have had the background on the div and used CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use:

```
<img src="<?php echo $slide['slide_image']; ?>" />
```

The `img` tag is for adding images to HTML.

If you actually want it as a background image, set it on a div:

```
<div style="background-image:url('<?php echo $slide['slide_image']; ?>')"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sumner really appreciate it.